# The perpendicular surface to a vector field

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

If a vector field $\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol x)$ is given where $\boldsymbol x$ is a given position point in an $n$-dimensional space and $\boldsymbol F$ is the velocity vector (Of course in the same dimensions).

Then, for any given arbitrary point $\boldsymbol x_0$, is there a closed hyper-surface $S$ (with $n-1$ dimensions) that

- crosses $\boldsymbol x_0$
- contains origin inside
- is perpendicular to $\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol x)$ everywhere on the surface.

?

How to check if this surface exists?

How to obtain this surface analytically?

---

I am after a solution that works for all fields and not a specific case.

Comment: Frobenius theorem.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, So many version of Frobenius theory. Which one do you mean?

Comment: @MoisheCohen, Is it about tangency or perpendicularity?

Comment: You can rephrase perpendicularly as tangency to the normal hyperplane field. Then your question is about integrability of a hyperplane field.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, Many thanks. Also, this theory looks very complicated. May I please ask you to explain it in a simple language?

Comment: I will write in a few days. In brief, you want to get a basis of vector fields normal to F and you want their Lie brackets to be normal to F as well.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, Hi Moishe, It would be great if I have your opinion about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586596/) special case as well.

Comment: I still do not have time....